# Keycloak angular redirect to login page when refresh token is expired

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am using anuglar keycloak library and there is a problem when both access token and refresh token are expired. When user clicks on some action to call BE API there is a call to keycloak server for token `openid-connect/token` and that returns:

```
error: "invalid_grant"
error_description: "Token is not active"
```

Thats is fine, but the problem is that nothing happens after that, and we want user to be redirected to login page when that happens. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution, there is keycloak event called `OnAuthRefreshError` that we can listen for and then redirect user to login page. Example:

```
  this.keycloakService.keycloakEvents$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.cancelSubscription$))
  .subscribe((event) => {
    if (event.type === KeycloakEventType.OnAuthRefreshError) {
      this.keycloakService.login({
        prompt: 'login',
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't get, why this is not the default behaviour in the library, but it solved my issue. (y)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it in my project in the service class I used:

```
    keycloakService.keycloakEvents$.subscribe({
  next(event) {
    if (event.type == KeycloakEventType.OnTokenExpired) {
      keycloakService.updateToken(20).then(updated => {
        if (!updated) {
          keycloakService.logout(environment.baseUrlFrontend+ "/logout"); 
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Using the keycloak-angular integration node package which provides prettymuch all you need for the case. I guess it would be nice to export this out of the angular service but I didn't dig deeper on that since it worked for me.